# Iphone app not showing properly on the device

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, ios-simulator

i have an app which works perfectly on the simulator but on the device in is not as expected. 
Animations are misplaced and other bugs. But on the simulator it works fine.

My question is how to fix this bug.
Here is list of things I already tried:

Restart Mac. 
Restart Xcode.
Clean Project.
Rename Project.
Delete app from iPhone. 
Restart iPhone.
Shut down iPhone. 
Clean and build in Xcode.

I really don't know where is the problem. 
Thank you for your help.
Would be really appreciated.

Notice: App is correctly signed.

Comment: Are the OS version different between the simulator and the device? How are you animation made? Can you be more specific regarding 'animations are not as expected'?

Comment: OS is the same iOS 5.1.1 and it doesn't consider only animations. it consider buttons, showing of imageViews...etc. If I launch the first time the view, animation is misplaced, but if I display it second time it is correct. Another issue with this - I have image view that is shown on demand of user. Button click. IBACTION is properly set, on simulator showing, but on device not....:-(

Answer (score 4):

Make sure your files typed correctly and are case sensitive. The Simulator is not case sensitive but the iPhone is.

Answer (score 1):

Did you ever move code/xib files into different groups or directories?  Sometimes there is a old copy of the file in the original directory after the move.  I've had scenarios in which those old files caused the old code to executed when switching between build settings.

If there are duplicate files, make sure you delete those copies at the old location, or those that you don't intend to be used.  For instance, if your original directory as `~/Work/App/Resources` and the new directory is `~/Work/App/Resources/xibs` then delete the duplicated files from `~/Work/App/Resources`

Make sense?

Now, after deletions, if files start to show up as red in XCode, that means XCode cannot find them anymore (maybe you deleted one too many, or who knows the state of your workspace).  If this happens, use the "File Inspector" to confirm that the location and path XCode is using for the file is correct.

[image]